# Using LLDB API to get the address of an expression in an elf file compiled with ARM-GCC

Tags: python, debugging, arm, embedded, lldb

Given an ARM .elf file with a nested structure in a .cpp file, I can use LLDB to evaluate an expression to get an address of a global structure/array element.

```
lldb my_arm.elf
(lldb) ex &user_data.sub_type[2].i[3]
```

This gives the expected result,

```
(int *) $1 = 0x200001f0
```

...similar to gdb, with a type, an index, and an address in RAM, for the C/C++ structure element specified. LLDB can also evaluate expressions like '&main', '1+1' etc.

Attempting to do the same thing in python using EvaluateExpression() in the lldb API, always results in  !IsValid().

```
import lldb  # this works in python in linux.
dbg = lldb.SBDebugger().Create()
dbg.SetAsync(False)
modspec = lldb.SBModuleSpec()
modspec.SetFileSpec(lldb.SBFileSpec("my_arm.elf"))
modspec.SetSymbolFileSpec(lldb.SBFileSpec("my_arm.elf"))
target.AddModule(modspec)  # target.IsValid() is True.
val=target.EvaluateExpression('&user_data.sub_type[2].i[3]')
```

This is python *outside* of lldb. `val.IsValid()` is always False and I can't seem to get values from the expressions. More trivial expressions like '&main' and '1+1' give similar results.

How can I use the lldb API to evaluate expressions for a .elf file?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to evaluate expressions w/o a running process.  The expression evaluator does have an interpreter mode, which it will fall back on when there's no running process, but that's not the main mode for the expression evaluator.  If you want to view global data `target var` is the preferred mode.  It also supports sub-element and array access, but of course doesn't call functions or do anything that would require executing code in the target process.  Also, the SBValue has an SBError (SBValue.GetError()) which will tell you why the expression failed.

Comment: Jim  Ingham, yes, I'm trying to evaluate expressions without running a process. These expressions are typically for cross-compiled .elf files so it's not feasible, or necessary, to run the process. Apparently, the .elf file has the necessary info to evaluate these expressions without running a process - lldb can do it, but my struggle was figuring out how to get the API to do the same thing. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So close. This simplification of your program gives the desired results.

```
import lldb
dbg = lldb.SBDebugger().Create()
target = dbg.CreateTarget("my_arm.elf")
val = target.EvaluateExpression("&user_data.sub_type[2].i[3]")
print("'{0}', type={1}, name={2}, value={3}, result={4}".format(val, val.type, val.name, val.value, val.GetError()))
```

and the results are:

```
'(int *) $0 = 0x200001f0', type=int *, name=$0, value=0x200001f0, result=success
```

...which is similar to the results that gdb gives but with more information about the value of the expression evaluated and it's done quickly, in-process, using the lldb library.